# Prove that $\sum_{r=1}^n f_i(a_r)=n, $ if $a_i$ is principal character & otherwise $0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$ with elements $a_1,a_2,\cdots ,a_n$ and let $f_1,f_2,\cdots , f_n$ be the characters of $G$ with $f_1$ is principal character. Let, $A=A(G)$ be the $n\times n$ matrix $[a_{ij}]$  whose elements $a_{ij}$ is the $i$-th row and $j$-th column is $a_{ij}=f_i(a_j)$.

[image]

> In the above theorem I'm unable to understand the red mark line. As, $G=\{a_1,\cdots , a_n\}$ so $b=a_k$ for some $k=1,\cdots ,n$. But how $\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^nf_i(a_r)=\sum_{r=1}^n f_i(ba_r)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Since $G$ is a group, multiplication on the left by any $b\in G$ is a bijection $G\to G$. Hence $ba_1,ba_2,\dots,ba_n$ is a permutation of $a_1,\dots,a_n$, so $\sum_{r=1}^{n}f_i(ba_r)=\sum_{r=1}^nf_i(a_r)$.

Comment: Permutation is OK. But how I can write the summations are equal from the permutation ?

Comment: Addition of complex numbers is commutative, so the sum of $n$ complex numbers does not depend on the order in which they are summed.